# Dual Booting Problems Windows 8.1/Ubuntu 14.04 Separate Hard Drives

Tags: dual-boot

I have Windows 8.1 on one hard drive and Ubuntu 14.04 on a second hard drive (installed in a HP Desktop).  My problem is that being a newbie I can not get Ubuntu to boot.  I tried a few things (i.e. EasyBCD) and none have worked.  Where or what have I done wrong?

Comment: have a look here http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708247/cant-boot-into-ubuntu-in-windows-10-ubuntu-dual-boot)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you need to change booting order, as your systems are installed in separate drives. On most computers when computer starts you can pop-up the boot menu, usually by pressing F12 of F10 key (message regarding the proper key is usually shown for a short time in the right bottom corner of the screen). Then choose the drive on which the Ubuntu is installed. If that works, and you would like to have such order always, you need to change the boot order in your BIOS settings.